# Haskell Range Map library

Tags: data-structures, haskell, dictionary, range, intervals

Is there a Haskell library that allows me to have a Map from ranges to values? (Preferable somewhat efficient.)

```
let myRangeMap = RangeMap [(range 1 3, "foo"),(range 2 7, "bar"),(range 9 12, "baz")]
in  rangeValues 2
==> ["foo","bar"]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This task is called a stabbing query on a set of intervals.  An efficient data structure for it is called (one-dimensional) [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).

The [SegmentTree package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SegmentTree) provides an implementation of this data structure, but unfortunately I cannot figure out how to use it.  (I feel that the interface of this package does not provide the right level of abstraction.)

Comment: I always love hearing about data structures for the first time. Very cool.

Answer (score 9):

I've written a library to search in overlapping intervals because the existing ones did not fit my needs. I think it may have a more approachable interface than for example SegmentTree:

https://www.chr-breitkopf.de/comp/IntervalMap/index.html

It's also available on Hackage: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/IntervalMap

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps the [`rangemin` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rangemin) does what you want?

Good old `Data.Map` (and its more efficient `Data.IntMap` cousin) has a function

```
splitLookup :: Ord k => k -> Map k a -> (Map k a, Maybe a, Map k a)
```

which splits a map into submaps of keys less than / greater than a given key.  This can be used for certain kinds of range searching.

Comment: Yes, Data.Map certainly is useful here.  I've used this quite successfully for "closest address to" type routing of network messages.  the `minView` and `maxView` along with their `*WithKeys` cousins are also useful.

Comment: `lookupLE` and friends (which are newer than this answer) are more efficient for this purpose when applicable, because they don't need to build new trees.